# Method resolution during logging: Why is ()->String.format(...) not recoginzed as Supplier<String>?

Tags: java, overloading, log4j2

I have made a call to the log4j-v2-API like this:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyLogger");

/**
 * syntactic sugar as part of a facade
 */
private void logAtLevel(String level, Supplier<String> messageSupplier, Throwable thrown){
      Level priority = Level.toLevel(level, Level.ALL);
      if (null == thrown) {
         logger.log(priority, messageSupplier);
      } else {
         logger.log(priority, messageSupplier, thrown);
      }

}

/**
 * method calling logger
 */
private void callLogging(Object value){
   logAtLevel("Debug", ()->String.format("something or other: %s", value), null);

}
```

My expectations would have been that the above call creates a log entry `"something or other: <object.toString()>"` however I got `"lambda@1223454"` instead.

This suggests to me that the method that was executed is [`log(level, object)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#log-org.apache.logging.log4j.Level-java.lang.Object-) rather than the expected [`log(level, supplier)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#log-org.apache.logging.log4j.Level-org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier-)

Why are the methods resolved the way they are and how can I prevent this (preferably without casting)?

Comment: There's something wrong with the `logAtLevel` call (a missing parenthesis). I suspect I know where it belongs, but it suggests that you're not showing us exactly the code that you're executing. Please [edit] your question to fix that.

Comment: Use `logger.log(priority, messageSupplier.get());` and `logger.log(priority, messageSupplier.get(), thrown);`. Currently, it's using `messageSupplier.toString()` and with this update, it will use `messageSupplier.get().toString()` giving you the desired result.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Thanks for the catch. I did not want to copy company code to stackO and retyped it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: I discarded this approach since it would defeat the benefit of the lazy evaluation of the log-message.

Comment: @leuchtstoffratte No, it will still be evaluated lazily.

Comment: *"something or other: <object.toString()>" however I got "lambda@1223454" instead.* to be strict, this is exactly what you get - lambda#toString(). Since you are wrapping that, you can try to cast it again (without any additional work ). I wonder if it will work then.

Comment: Maybe you are not using that version of Logger you think you do :)

Comment: Eclipse gives the method as `void org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.log(Level level, Object message)` if I use the code as is and `void org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.log(Level level, String message)` if I append a get() as Arvind suggested.

Comment: but be aware that `get()` will be evaluated when (before) the `log()` method is called, no matter if logging is enabled or not for given `Level` - that is, NOT lazy! In Eclipse you can check which `Logger` is being used, from which Library (seems like an older version, based on API doc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Supplier` is not Log4j2's `Supplier`!

[`java.util.function.Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) was introduced in Java 8. At around the same time (version 2.4, cf. [LOG4J2-599](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-599)) Log4j2 introduced [`org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Supplier.html) so that the library can be used on Java 7.

That is why your code does not call `log(Level, Supplier<?>, Throwable)` but `log(Level, Object, Throwable)` and you end up with `Supplier#toString()` being logged instead of `Supplier#get()`.

This is probably something that should change and I filed a wish list bug about it (cf. [#1262](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1262)).

**Remark:** Wrapping well established logging APIs like Log4j2 API and SLF4J into custom wrappers is not a good idea (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75256959/11748454)). While it is not rocket science to write a good wrapper, there are many details you should consider. For example your wrapper breaks location information.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a level lookup for every call, when your intent is to avoid every nanosecond for levels that don't matter, is probably something you need to reconsider.

At any rate, there is nothing immediately obvious about your snippet that would explain what you observe. Thus, let's get into debugging it, and likely causes.

1. The code you are running isn't the code you wrote. For example, because you haven't (re)compiled.
2. `logger.log` is overloaded, and older versions of slf4j exist that contain only the 'object' variant, which just calls toString(), which would lead to precisely the behaviour you are now witnessing.

You can do some debugging on both of these problems by applying the following trick:

- Add `System.out.println(TheClassThisCodeIsIn.class.getResource("TheClassThisCodeIsIn.class"));` - this will tell you *exactly* where the class file is at.
- Then use `javap -v -c path/to/that/file.class` and check the actual call to logger.log - is the 'signature' that it links to the `Supplier` variant or the `Object` variant?

The different effects and what it means:

- The sysout call isn't showing up. Then you aren't running the code you are looking at, and you need to investigate your toolstack. How are you compiling it, because it's not working.
- The javap output shows that the 'Object' variant is invoked. In which case **the compilation step** is using an old version of log4j2 in its classpath. It's not about the slf4j version that exists at runtime, it's what the compiler is using, as that determines which overload is chosen.
- Everything looks fine and yet you are still seeing `lambda@...` - then I would start suspecting that this is the *actual output* of your lambda code somehow, or something really, really wonky is going on. The only things I can think of that get you here are ridiculously exotic, not worth mentioning.