# How to use logger with caller class to get better performance?

Tags: java, log4j2

I have following class but if we are creating objects multiple times then what will be use of static

```
class MyLogger {

    static Logger logger;

    public MyLogger(Class cls) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(cls.getName());
    }

    public MyLogger(String name) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
    }
}
```

I want to improve performance of logging and I am using my own caller class for logging.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve here, and why not just declaring static fields of type `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` in classes where you want to log is sufficient for your needs. That is the normal pattern. In addition, declaring `logger` to be static here is **wrong**, because the last `MyLogger` constructor to have been called "wins", which goes against wanting to create loggers per class or per name.

Comment: Custom logging APIs or wrappers cause a lot of problem with almost no advantages, use Log4j2 API directly. Cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75256959/11748454).